# How do I install the JMF 2.1.1e [2014]

Tags: java, jmf

So I Downloaded JMF from here:http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/download-142937.html installed it(There was only an installation wizard version).

Then what am I meant to do? java had no docs on it the documentation that came with the download just said in a nutshell run the wizard.

Is it just meant to work like some kind of magical java package? I launched eclipses to see If I could use the javax.media.*; package but nope it still does not exist.

I have read many threads on this but they are from 2013 and don't really help.. As I am sure it was different then.

Is eclipse missing something.. Is anyone able to import the JMF packages in eclipse?

Tell me its not just a myth and infact one can use the new JMF in eclipse.

Where should the packadge be installed it once again siad nothing in the documentation about if it should go in a jre bin or jdk bin...

I feel like the underpants gnomes from south park. RunWizard --> ? --> Profit. Like I am missing something important but I cant find that peice of information anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default installation should have created a directory

> C:\Program Files (x86)\JMF2.1.1e\lib

where the "jmf.jar" is located. You'll need to include this JAR as one of the "referenced libraries" in Eclipse.